# How to execute command and use it's result in sed correctly?

Tags: macos, sed

I have a config file in JSON format with following block

```
"device" :
{
    "name"       : "MyPi",
    "type"       : "ws2801",
    "output"     : "/dev/spidev0.0",
    "rate"       : 250000,
    "colorOrder" : "rgb"
},
```

I use sed (non GNU version on OS X) to replace the string values with sed expression like this:
`sed -i '' '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s#\("device" :[^}]*"colorOrder"[ ]*: \)"[^"]*"#\1"grb"#' hyperion.config.json`

Now I want to replace "output": line with the result of `ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*` with this command:
`sed -i '' -e '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s#\("device" :[^}]*"output"[ ]*: \)"[^"]*"#\1"$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)"#' hyperion.config.json`
However `ls` is not executed and I get `"output"     : "$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)",`
I tried replacing single quotes with double quotes with escaping inside the expression, that didn't work.

So how can I replace the value of the output (inside the "device" block) with the output of `ls` command?

Comment: You need to replace the single-quotes by double-quotes. Most of the existing double-quotes are superfluous, apart from those where in the search pattern, and these should be escaped.

Comment: result of `sed -i '' -e "1h;1!H;$!d;x;s#\(\"device\" :[^}]*\"output\"[ ]*: \)\"[^\"]*\"#\1\"$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)\"#" hyperion.config.json` is `-bash: !H: event not found`. With escaped exclamation marks: `sed -i '' -e "1h;1\!H;$\!d;x;s#\(\"device\" :[^}]*\"output\"[ ]*: \)\"[^\"]*\"#\1\"$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)\"#" hyperion.config.json`: `sed: 1: "1h;1\!H;$\!d;x;s#\("dev ...": invalid command code \ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the part (inside the single quotes)

```
$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)
```

by

```
'"$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)"'
```

hence exiting the single quote part and entering a double quote for the command, then reentering single quote.

Comment: I was going to propose this solution, but it fails if `/dev/tty.usbmodem*` matches more than one file (or none). In order to handle multiple matches, you need `$(echo $(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*))`. But I don't see the purpose of `ls`, unless it has some default options: surely it is a lot simpler to replace `"$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)"` by `"/dev/tty.usbmodem*"`.

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes like in the example below.

Replace:

```
'xxx"$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)"xxx'
```

by:

```
'xxx"'"$(ls /dev/tty.usbmodem*)"'"xxx'
```